# Could Voldemort possess Nagini?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Could Voldemort ever fully possess Nagini or was their telepathic bond intensely strong so that Nagini would do anything that Voldemort said?

> "But the man was stirring... a silver Cloak fell from his legs as he jumped to his feet; and Harry saw his vibrant, blurred outline towering above him, saw a wand withdrawn from a belt... he had no choice... he reared high from the floor and struck once, twice, three times, plunging his fangs deeply into the mans flesh, feeling his ribs splinter beneath his jaws, feeling the warm gush of blood... The man was yelling in pain... then he fell silent... he slumped backwards against the wall... blood was splattering on to the floor...."

In this scene Harry was supposedly seeing through Voldemort's mind. Yet how could Voldemort see through Nagini if Legilimency only shows memories, not current events? Is their telepathic connection so strong that he can see into her mind at will?

Comment: I know Horcruxes are supposed not to be linked with one's "original" piece of soul (see how Voldemort didn't sense the Horcruxes being destroyed), but maybe having a bit of his soul inside Nagini helps?

Comment: yeh i guess... to a certain extent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Yes.

Voldemort could indeed possess Nagini, and did so on the trip to the Ministry referenced in the question.

> "You seem to have visited the snake's mind because that was where the Dark Lord was at that particular moment," snarled Snape. "He was possessing the snake at the time and so you dreamed you were inside it, too."
>   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 24, Occlumency)*.</sub>

Voldemort didn't need to use Legilimency on Nagini in this instance because he was possessing her instead. Harry saw Nagini's thoughts/perspective because Voldemort was in her at the time. He couldn't have seen inside Nagini's head otherwise.

Comment: ok i couldnt find confirmation about the possesing buisness thank you :)

Comment: Of course _you_ would know. (c'mon someone had to make the joke :p )

Comment: What do you mean, joke?